# How to non-mass-assigned without attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model `Widget` that accepts `:title`, `:url`, `:description` as user input via a front-end form.

In this model, I ultimately don't care about the `:url` (meaning I don't want to store it). What I do care about however are 2 pieces of data in the `:url`, an `:appname` and a `username`.

On the otherhand, i DONT want `:appname` and `:username` to be mass-assigned or accessible in any way to the public (to make it simple, its very hard to validate them due to the source continually changing). What I do is validate the URL strictly and that is enough, and where those parts are in the url i have much more lax rules in the regex).

I'm not sure how to set this up though in the model itself. This is what I have so far

`attr_accessible :description, :title, :url`

However, how do I write `:username` and `:appname` if they aren't attr_accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only to write non ActiveRecord attributes to your model instance you can use

```
attr_writer :username, :appname
```

in your model.

Or use

```
attr_accessor :username, :appname
```

if you want to set/get it later to/from active_record `:url` attribute.

Comment: what if I want to pull them out later?